# Iterate two collections in one loop

Tags: scala

What is the elegant way to iterate two collections in Scala using one loop?

I want set values from first collection to second, like this:

```
// pseudo-code
for (i <- 1 to 10) {
  val value = collection1.get(i);
  collection2.setValueAtIndex(value, i) ;
}
```

In fact I use `Iterable` trait, so its better if you provide solution applicable for `Iterable`.

Please note: I don't want to copy values from one to another. I need to access in loop to `i`'th element of first and second collection
Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to copy the first 10 elements? Why not just do that?

Comment: @Marcin no, I need access in loop to both elements: from first and from second collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to access each element at the same index from both collections, you could `zip` the two collections:

```
for((e1, e2) <- collection1 zip collection2) {
  //Do something with e1 and e2
  //e1 is from collection1 and e2 is from collection2
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't look like you want to iterate the second collection at all, but want the index of the thing you're working on, which is what `zipWithIndex` is good for:

```
for ((el, i) <- collection1.zipWithIndex) {
  collection2.setValueAtIndex(el, i)
}
```